# How to sum total observations in one dataset per ID that occur within time interval of another dataset

Tags: r, date, sum, rows, lubridate

I have two datasets: DF1 - data frame which lists heads of states (leader_id) of countries (country_code) and an interval of their time in office (office_interval).  DF2 - data frame where every observation is an event that has the country (country_code) and date it occurred (event_date).

reproducible data:

```
library(lubridate)

#Leader DF
leader_id <- c("Adam","Bob","Charlie")
country_code <- c(1,1,2)
office_interval <- c(interval(ymd("1900-01-01"), ymd("1905-01-01")), 
                     interval(ymd("1910-01-01"), ymd("1915-01-01")),
                     interval(ymd("1920-01-01"), ymd("1925-01-01")))
DF1 <- data.frame(leader_id, country_code, office_interval)

#Event DF
country_code <- c(1,2,2,1)
event_date <- c(as.Date("1901-01-01"), 
                as.Date("1902-01-01"), 
                as.Date("1921-01-01"),
                as.Date("1901-02-02"))
DF2 <- data.frame(country_code, event_date)
```

I would like to create a new column, DF1$total_events, that sums the total number of observations in DF2 that occur within the same country_code and office_interval for each leader in DF1.  It should look like this:

```
    leader_id    country_code1          office_interval         total_events
1      Adam             1       1900-01-01 UTC--1905-01-01 UTC       2
2       Bob             1       1910-01-01 UTC--1915-01-01 UTC       0
3     Charlie           2       1920-01-01 UTC--1925-01-01 UTC       1
```

I've tried to modify some solutions from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345651/in-r-how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group-between-two-dates?rq=1), however i can't get anything to work on my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `left_join` on `DF1` and `DF2` by `"country_code"` and count number of `event_date` within `office_interval`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2, by = "country_code") %>%
  group_by(leader_id, country_code, office_interval) %>%
  summarise(total_events = sum(event_date %within% office_interval))

#  leader_id country_code office_interval                total_events
#  <fct>            <dbl> <Interval>                            <int>
#1 Adam                 1 1900-01-01 UTC--1905-01-01 UTC            2
#2 Bob                  1 1900-01-01 UTC--1905-01-01 UTC            0
#3 Charlie              2 1910-01-01 UTC--1915-01-02 UTC            1
```

Comment: great, it looks like its doing it in the console but how do I get it to be a new column in DF1?

Comment: @BobC you need to assign it to an object `DF3 <- DF1 %>%
  left_join(DF2, by = "country_code") %>%
  group_by(leader_id, country_code, office_interval) %>%
  summarise(total_events = sum(event_date %within% office_interval))`, check `DF3` then.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(DF1)[DF2, on = .(country_code)][, .(total_events = 
   sum(event_date %within% office_interval)), 
           .(leader_id, country_code, new = office_interval)]
```