# R Sum values between two dates WITHOUT repetition

Tags: r, date, data.table, cumulative-sum

I have the following dataset:

**Data:**

[image]

I would like to sum, by group, the values ​​of all events that started within 60 days *(already calculated interval = Start_interval, End_interval)* **without adding the same row in more than one interval.**

**Expected output:**

[image]

I did research and found some solutions that allowed me to obtain, until then, the results displayed below, very close to what I expected. For example: [In R: how to sum a variable by group between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345651/in-r-how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group-between-two-dates)

The difference between the questions is that I need the sum to be performed **without adding, by group, the same row in more than one period.**

**Result I got so far:**

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Reproducible example:**

```
# Input data
data <- data.table(id = c("Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group A",
                          "Group A", "Group A"),
                   start_date_event = c("2019-09-15",
                                        "2019-11-24",
                                        "2020-04-19",
                                        "2020-04-25",
                                        "2020-05-25",
                                        "2020-10-27"),
                     end_date_event = c("2019-09-24",
                                        "2019-11-28",
                                        "2020-04-23",
                                        "2020-04-29",
                                        "2020-05-27",
                                        "2020-11-06"),
                     start_interval = c("2019-09-15",
                                        "2019-11-24",
                                        "2020-04-19",
                                        "2020-04-25",
                                        "2020-05-25",
                                        "2020-10-27"),
                       end_interval = c("2019-11-14",
                                        "2020-01-23",
                                        "2020-06-18",
                                        "2020-06-24",
                                        "2020-07-24",
                                        "2020-12-26"),
                     value = c(9, 4, 4, 4, 2, 15))

# Convert to date
data <- data %>%
        dplyr::mutate(start_date_event = as.Date(start_date_event)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(end_date_event = as.Date(end_date_event)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(start_interval = as.Date(start_interval)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(end_interval = as.Date(end_interval))

# Calculating with non-equi join
temp <- data[data,
          on = .(start_date_event <= end_interval,
                 end_date_event >= start_interval)][,
          .(value_sum = sum(value)),
          by = .(id, start_date_event)]

# Get all
data <- merge(data, temp, all.x = T,
              by.x = c("id", "end_interval"),
              by.y = c("id", "start_date_event"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: In row 3 of the expected output, should the value_sum=4? (It shows 10)

Comment: @langtang In row 3 from the expected output, there is an event that starts on '2020-04-19'. From that date, I would like to sum all events/rows that occurred within a period of 60 days (thus between 2020-04-19 to 2020-06-18). Both lines 3, 4, and 5 occurred within a period of 60 days (this means, these are events that started within the 60-day interval calculated for line 3). For this reason, the result is 10 (​​4+4+2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option..

First, change to dates (this is like your dplyr/mutate statement above)

```
data <- cbind(data[, .(id, value)], data[, lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = c(2,3,4,5)])
```

Add an event_id column, within group

```
data[order(id,start_date_event), event_id:=1:.N, id]
```

Get a table of unique "periods" by id and key the table, for use in `foverlaps`

```
periods <- data[, .(id, start_interval, end_interval)][, period:=1:.N, by=id]
setkey(periods, id, start_interval, end_interval)
```

Use fast overlaps to associate a period with each event, then get the minimum period for each event, and the sum of values by each period

```
period_id <- foverlaps(data, periods, by.x = c("id", "start_date_event", "end_date_event"))
```

Create the value sum column via these steps

```
# Get the value_sums, by merging the minimum period by event
# with the sum over the values by period
value_sums = period_id[,.(period = min(period)),
          by=.(id, event_id)][
            period_id[
              , .(value_sum = sum(value)),
              by = .(id, period)],
            on=.(id, period), nomatch=0]

# convert the value sum column to zero if it is not the first row, by associated period
value_sums[order(id,event_id, period),value_sum:=value_sum*((1:.N)==1), by=.(id, period)]


# merge back on to data (dropping the period column)
data[value_sums[, !c("period")], on=.(id,event_id)]
```

Output:

```
        id value start_date_event end_date_event start_interval end_interval event_id value_sum
1: Group A     9       2019-09-15     2019-09-24     2019-09-15   2019-11-14        1         9
2: Group A     4       2019-11-24     2019-11-28     2019-11-24   2020-01-23        2         4
3: Group A     4       2020-04-19     2020-04-23     2020-04-19   2020-06-18        3        10
4: Group A     4       2020-04-25     2020-04-29     2020-04-25   2020-06-24        4         0
5: Group A     2       2020-05-25     2020-05-27     2020-05-25   2020-07-24        5         0
6: Group A    15       2020-10-27     2020-11-06     2020-10-27   2020-12-26        6        15
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a seemingly-complicated approach that gets your results:

```r
data[, rn := seq_len(.N)
  ][data, on = .(id, start_date_event >= start_interval, end_date_event <= end_interval)
  ][, z := fifelse(rleid(i.rn) > 1, 0, value), by = rn
  ][, value_sum := sum(z), by = i.rn
  ][, .SD[1,], .SDcols = patterns("^.[^.]"), by=.(i.rn)
  ][, c("rn", "i.rn") := NULL ]
#         id start_date_event end_date_event start_interval end_interval value value_sum
#     <char>           <Date>         <Date>         <Date>       <Date> <num>     <num>
# 1: Group A       2019-09-15     2019-11-14     2019-09-15   2019-11-14     9         9
# 2: Group A       2019-11-24     2020-01-23     2019-11-24   2020-01-23     4         4
# 3: Group A       2020-04-19     2020-06-18     2020-04-19   2020-06-18     4        10
# 4: Group A       2020-04-25     2020-06-24     2020-04-25   2020-06-24     4         0
# 5: Group A       2020-05-25     2020-07-24     2020-05-25   2020-07-24     2         0
# 6: Group A       2020-10-27     2020-12-26     2020-10-27   2020-12-26    15        15
```